# Handling InternetCloseHandle failure

Tags: c++, winapi, wininet

**INTRODUCTION AND RELEVANT INFORMATION:**

I am learning WinInet on my own. I have written (in my humble opinion) "typical" piece of code, that needs to perform cleanup in the end:

```
DWORD CSomeClass::MVCE4StackOverflow()
{
    DWORD errorCode = ERROR_SUCCESS;

    URL_COMPONENTS urlComp;

    ::ZeroMemory(&urlComp, sizeof(URL_COMPONENTS));
    urlComp.dwStructSize = sizeof(URL_COMPONENTS);
    urlComp.dwHostNameLength    = -1;
    urlComp.dwSchemeLength      = -1;
    urlComp.dwUrlPathLength     = -1;

    if (!::InternetCrackUrl(m_URL.c_str(), m_URL.length(), 0, &urlComp))
    {
        errorCode = ::GetLastError();
        return errorCode;
    }

    HINTERNET hInternetSession = ::InternetOpen("WinInet",
                                     INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, 
                                     NULL, NULL, 0);

    if (NULL == hInternetSession)
    {
        errorCode = ::GetLastError();
        return errorCode;
    }

    std::string hostname(urlComp.dwHostNameLength, 0);
    ::memcpy(&hostname[0], urlComp.lpszHostName, urlComp.dwHostNameLength);

    HINTERNET hHttpSession = ::InternetConnect(hInternetSession, 
                             hostname.c_str(), 
                             INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, 0, 0, 
                             INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, NULL);

    if (NULL == hHttpSession)
    {
        errorCode = ::GetLastError();
        return errorCode;
    }

    HINTERNET hHttpRequest = ::HttpOpenRequest(hHttpSession, "POST", 
                             urlComp.lpszUrlPath, 0, 0, 0, 
                             INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0);

    if (NULL == hHttpRequest)
    {
        errorCode = ::GetLastError();
        return errorCode;
    }

    const char header[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    std::string data = "input=1234";

    if (!::HttpSendRequest(hHttpRequest, header, strlen(header), 
        &data[0], data.length()))
    {
        errorCode = ::GetLastError();
        return errorCode;
    }

    DWORD dwBytesRead = 0;
    BOOL result = false;

    char szBuffer[1025] = "";
    char *temp = szBuffer;
    const DWORD dwBytes2Read = sizeof(szBuffer) - 1;

    do{

        result = ::InternetReadFile(hHttpRequest, szBuffer, dwBytes2Read, &dwBytesRead);

        if (FALSE == result)
        {
            errorCode = ::GetLastError();
        }

        temp += dwBytesRead;

    } while (result && dwBytesRead > 0);

    // need error handling for below 3 
    result = ::InternetCloseHandle(hHttpRequest);
    result = ::InternetCloseHandle(hHttpSession);
    result = ::InternetCloseHandle(hInternetSession);

    return errorCode;   
}
```

**PROBLEM:**

In the provided code example, I need to call `InternetCloseHandle` 3 times consecutively.

I do not know how to structure that part of code to perform proper error handling.

My idea would be to do do the following:

```
result = ::InternetCloseHandle(hHttpRequest);
if(result)
{
    result = ::InternetCloseHandle(hHttpSession);
    if (result) 
    {
        result = ::InternetCloseHandle(hInternetSession);
        if(!result) return ::GetLastError();
    }
    else return ::GetLastError();
}
else return ::GetLastError();
```

However, being new to WinInet, I am not sure if my solution is correct.

**QUESTION:**

Can you please instruct me on how to handle the scenario in the provided code example?

*I understand that my question might be confusing, but please take into consideration that English is not my native. Please leave a comment seeking further clarifications.*

**UPDATE #1:**

I have tried to apply RAII:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <WinInet.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Wininet.lib")

class CInternetOpenRAII
{
    HINTERNET hIntSession;

public:

    CInternetOpenRAII(){}

    HINTERNET get() const { return hIntSession; }

    DWORD init()
    {
        hIntSession = ::InternetOpen("WinInet", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);

        return hIntSession ? ERROR_SUCCESS : ::GetLastError();
    }

    ~CInternetOpenRAII()
    { 
        if(hIntSession) 
        {
            if(!::InternetCloseHandle(hIntSession)) 
            {
                std::cerr << "InternetOpen failed with GetLastErrorCode: " << ::GetLastError();
            }
        }
    }
};

class CInternetConnectRAII
{
    HINTERNET hHttpSession;

public:

    CInternetConnectRAII() {}

    HINTERNET get() const { return hHttpSession; }

    DWORD init(const HINTERNET &hIntSession, const char *url)
    {
        hHttpSession = ::InternetConnect(hIntSession, url, INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, 0, 0, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, NULL);

        return hHttpSession ? ERROR_SUCCESS : ::GetLastError();
    }

    ~CInternetConnectRAII()
    {
        if(hHttpSession) 
        {
            if(!::InternetCloseHandle(hHttpSession)) 
            {
                std::cerr << "InternetConnect failed with GetLastErrorCode: " << ::GetLastError();
            }
        }
    }
};

class CHttpOpenRequestRAII
{
    HINTERNET hHttpRequest;

public:

    CHttpOpenRequestRAII() {}

    HINTERNET get() const { return hHttpRequest; }

    DWORD init(const HINTERNET &hHttpSession, const char *request)
    {
        hHttpRequest = ::HttpOpenRequest(hHttpSession, "POST", request, 0, 0, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0);

        return hHttpRequest ? ERROR_SUCCESS : ::GetLastError(); 
    }

    DWORD doRequest(const char *data, size_t dataLength, const char *header, size_t headerLength)
    {
        if (!::HttpSendRequest(hHttpRequest, header, headerLength, (void *)data, dataLength))
            return ::GetLastError();

        CHAR szBuffer[10] = "";
        DWORD dwRead = 0;
        const int dwBytes2Read = sizeof(szBuffer) - 1;

        while (::InternetReadFile(hHttpRequest, szBuffer, dwBytes2Read, &dwRead) && dwRead)
        {
            std::cout << szBuffer;
        }

        return ERROR_SUCCESS;
    }

    ~CHttpOpenRequestRAII()
    {
        if(hHttpRequest) 
        {
            if(!::InternetCloseHandle(hHttpRequest)) 
            {
                std::cerr << "HttpOpenRequest failed with GetLastErrorCode: " << ::GetLastError();
            }
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    DWORD error = ERROR_SUCCESS;

    CInternetOpenRAII session;

    error = session.init();
    if(error) return error;

    CInternetConnectRAII conn;

    error = conn.init(session.get(), "www.test.com");
    if(error) return error;

    CHttpOpenRequestRAII req;

    error = req.init(conn.get(), "/home/something");
    if(error) return error;

    error = req.doRequest("parameter=1234", strlen("parameter=1234"),
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", strlen("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
    if(error) return error;

    return 0;
}
```

Now I do not know how to handle error in destructor. Can somebody please look at the code and provide some advice on that?

Comment: Write RAII wrapper classes for the resources that you need to manage their life-times.

Comment: You have far deeper problems. You may succeed in creating the first handle, but then fail to create the second handle. At that point your current code leaks that first handle. Either use an RAII approach, which is how I would do it, or stick to the class C style approach with a `goto cleanup` style.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Thank you David. I missed your catch because I was in a hurry... I will try to do RAII on my own, but would welcome some guidance in view of instructions or some pseudo code (just to point me in the right dirrection). Thanks again.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: David, I have updated my post with RAII applied. Seems much better now, however I don't know how to handle the case when error happens in destructor. For now I just output notification through `std::cerr`. Can you take a brief look at the newly posted code and offer some advice? Thank you.

Comment: It is like the movie, *you can't handle the truth*.  This is a very, very serious mishap with significant odds that memory corruption is behind it.  Leaving the program running is a grossly bad idea, especially so when doing internetty stuff.  Just make sure you can see programming bugs, use assert().  Then [fail fast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn774154.aspx).

Comment: Your RAII wrappers are not designed very well. If the code basically works now, I suggest taking it over to [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get better advise. For instance, always initialize the handle members to `NULL`. Also, if you have RAII wrappers, it cries for error handling via exceptions instead of "C-style" error return values.